# How to set up a .local domain on Linx?

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, home-networking, nginx

I have multiple nginx virtual hosts all pointing to localhost. Right now they have same name different ports `localhost:8080`, `localhost:8081`. Instead I'd like them to have same port different names `site1:8080`, `site2:8080`.

However this requires me to add new entries to `/etc/hosts/` for each site:

```
127.0.0.1 site1 site2 site3 site4
```

Instead is there a way to create a `.local` domain so that anything typed ending with that would be resolved to localhost? This way I could do `site1.local:8080`, `site2.local:8080` and not have to update /etc/hosts each time. Something like

```
127.0.0.1 .local
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

What are some ways I could make it work without having to set up something like `dnsmasq`?

I've heard about http://readme.localtest.me/ which allows doing it with `site1.localtest.me:8080` but I do a lot of work without internet connections so I'd ideally use something that doesn't require being online to resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Anything I could do with `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/resolv.conf` or something else that could work for setting up a .local domain?

Comment: Only one process can bind to a port at a time, so you will need to run a proxy server to redirect requests from the different domains to the necessary ports.

Comment: @Josh: Not neccessary. The same HTTP service process can easily serve many different domains [on the same address.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)

Comment: Oops, must have misread the question. I got it into my head that there were multiple testing servers running as seperate processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in `/etc/hosts`. There no way to do this without DNS server.

You have two options:
1) Put every custom host that you need in `/etc/hosts` (you could automate it with a custom shell script)

2) Simply use a custom local DNS for this task. I would recommend [dnsmasq](http://dnsmasq.org).

You just have to use `--address=/local/127.0.0.1` parameter in dnsmasq, where "local" is your domain name.

Comment: I'm trying your dnsmasq suggestion but haven't been able to get it to work would you mind taking a look at the question I just posted http://superuser.com/questions/785746/dnsmasq-not-working-to-point-local-addresses-to-127-0-0-1?