# dnsmasq not working to point .local addresses to 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I'd like to get `.local` addresses (such as test.local) to point to `127.0.0.1` but it isn't working. I'm on latest Ubuntu. In /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf I commented out `dns=dnsmasq` then did `sudo service network-manager restart`.

I then installed dnsmasq and added a `address=/local/127.0.0.1` to /etc/dnsmasq.d/mycustomfile then did `sudo service dnsmasq restart`. Apart from what I've mentioned I made no other changes.

But when I visit test.local it doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1, doing a ping of that .local address also isn't successful. Maybe the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are relevant, it is just the default I didn't change it:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 222.11.22.36
nameserver 222.11.22.37
```

This is the output when I run dnsmasq not as a daemon:

```
$ sudo dnsmasq --no-daemon     
dnsmasq: started, version 2.68 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth
dnsmasq: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq: using nameserver 222.11.22.37#53
dnsmasq: using nameserver 222.11.22.36#53
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 9 addresses
```

When dnsmasq is running the /etc/resolv.conf automatically updates (and reverts back to the entry above when dnsmasq is stopped):

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And this:

```
$ sudo nslookup test.local 127.0.0.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   test.local
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

But still doing a ping to localhost doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get dnsmasq working to resolve .local addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`local` seem to be some kind of reserved keyword, at least on Ubuntu:

- `address=/local/127.0.0.1` -- doesn't work.
- `address=/loc/127.0.0.1` -- works.

Comment: rand'Chris: Thank you for trying to improve an answer on [SU]. But, while many people believe that it’s OK to correct errors in other people’s posts, and add small clarifications, your suggested edit is **so** substantial that (IMHO) it should be posted as a separate answer. It’s OK to repeat (some) information from a previous answer as long as you add something of value. (You should of course identify the answer that you are building on, by linking to it and citing the author’s name.) You might also want to refer to [this other rejected edit](/review/suggested-edits/744832).

Answer (score 9):

Looks like dnsmasq is starting correctly. You should test if dnsmasq is correctly working with `nslookup test.local 127.0.0.1`.

To make sure the system is using dnsmasq, you have to update the `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `nameserver 127.0.0.1` as first option.

You can also use a custo upstream resolver configuration on dnsmasq with `--resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf.dnsmasq`.

Comment: I have updated my question with some information based on your answer, I'd appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: Also the original `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file is left as it was originally, with everything commented out. Are there things I need to uncomment from there? (It's a large file over 600 lines.) The only thing I uncommented was the last line `conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d` because my custom config file is under that directory.

Comment: Your dnsmasq is responding correctly. The `conf-dir` directive does load all files inside the directory, so you can have organize in different files, not necessary needed in your case. You can keep the original dnsmasq.conf as it is and put your configuration in a custom file in /etc/dnsmasq.d, as you've already done. You don't need sudo to run nslookup. Test again with `nslookup test.local`, it will use the DNS configuration from `/etc/resolv.conf` this time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the avahi-daemon is using the domain "local". See:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352237/avahi-daemon-and-local-domain-issues

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please **edit your answer** so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want only involves pointing back at your own machine, and not trying to use dnsmasq to control other computers' dns resolving, then what you want is to actually just add some entries in `/etc/hosts`. I'd recommenced you undo all your changes to dnsmasq and it's settings and make sure that `/etc/hosts` has the following at the top:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mycomputername mycomputername.local anothername.local
```

After this, pinging mycomputername.local will point to yourself (actually, will point to dnsmasq server running on 127.0.1.1, THEN to localhost). You can even add entries for other computers on your network so that it appears to you, on this machine, that computers can be referenced as `computer1.local` `computer2.local` etc.

```
192.168.1.31 computer1.local
192.168.1.32 computer2.local
```

If you can't seem to undo your changes with dnsmasq, then you can add those additional entries after `localhost`, but do not delete or change the `localhost` entry itself. So like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mycomputername mycomputername.local anothername.local
```

---

BTW: the proper way to modify resolv.conf on Ubuntu desktop is with the network manager in your taskbar. The proper way in Ubuntu server is add `dns-nameserver` entries under your network device in `/etc/network/interfaces` and either restart or do `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`. As the warning in `/etc/resolv.conf` states, don't modify it directly, it gets written dynamically based on `/etc/network/interfaces` settings.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` does not allow wildcards, you'd have to update it for every new `.local` domain, that's why people use dnsmasq even for local resolving.